# Module not found: Can't resolve "process" while importing axios into NextJs

Tags: axios, next.js

I'm getting the following error:

```
./node_modules/axios/lib/defaults/index.js:23:4
Module not found: Can't resolve 'process'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js
./node_modules/axios/index.js
./pages/index.js
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

```
Home.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/restaurants');
    const restaurants = res.data;
    return { restaurants };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Which versions of `node` and `next` are you using? Have you tried a clean build by deleting the `.next` and `build` directories before running `next dev` or `next start`?

Comment: "next": "12.1.0", node  v16.13.1 and yes I tried to clean the build but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 config.resolve.fallback = {
      process: false,
    };
```

this trick solved my issue. Thanks